# AWK how to change lines in specific step in awk?

Tags: awk

My fragment of my input:

```
1BGL    HO215593   3.915  12.459   9.510  0.7361  0.5777 -0.8536
1BGL     C315594   3.857  12.492   9.774  0.2903 -0.0441 -0.1309
1BGL     H315595   3.832  12.596   9.751 -1.5776 -0.7625 -1.5600
1BGL     O315596   3.751  12.409   9.734 -0.2728  0.1281 -1.1830
1BGL    HO315597   3.765  12.318   9.754 -0.2825 -0.0472 -1.9431
1BGL     O415858   6.570   4.320  11.610  0.3536  0.6453 -0.6513
1BGL    HO415859   6.659   4.351  11.619  0.0436  1.3871 -0.0553
1BGL    H6115861   6.645   4.607  11.335  2.0665 -1.6099 -1.7335
1BGL    H6215862   6.721   4.472  11.418 -0.2311  0.3617  1.3831
1BGL     O615863   6.688   4.666  11.503  0.0747 -0.9278  0.2467
1BGL    HO615864   6.676   4.744  11.451  0.9074 -1.0786 -0.1851
1BGL     C515972   4.449  18.685  10.426  0.7000 -0.4471  0.3442
1BGL     H515973   4.528  18.725  10.363 -0.4525  1.0824 -0.1756
1BGL     O515974   4.342  18.651  10.331  0.1934  0.1445  0.2786
1BGL     C115975   4.322  18.744  10.238  0.0047 -0.4785  0.1790
1BGL     H115976   4.416  18.778  10.194 -0.9920  1.9578 -0.2411
1BGL     C215977   4.251  18.864  10.310 -0.6103  0.0598 -0.3355
1BGL     H215978   4.153  18.842  10.352  0.6769 -0.5089  2.5981
```

I want to have output like that

```
1BGL    HO215593   3.915  12.459   9.510  0.7361  0.5777 -0.8536
1BGL     C315594   3.857  12.492   9.774  0.2903 -0.0441 -0.1309
1BGL     H315595   3.832  12.596   9.751 -1.5776 -0.7625 -1.5600
1BGL     O315596   3.751  12.409   9.734 -0.2728  0.1281 -1.1830
1BGL    HO315597   3.765  12.318   9.754 -0.2825 -0.0472 -1.9431
1BGL     O415858   6.570   4.320  11.610  0.3536  0.6453 -0.6513
2BGL    HO415859   6.659   4.351  11.619  0.0436  1.3871 -0.0553
2BGL    H6115861   6.645   4.607  11.335  2.0665 -1.6099 -1.7335
2BGL    H6215862   6.721   4.472  11.418 -0.2311  0.3617  1.3831
2BGL     O615863   6.688   4.666  11.503  0.0747 -0.9278  0.2467
2BGL    HO615864   6.676   4.744  11.451  0.9074 -1.0786 -0.1851
2BGL     C515972   4.449  18.685  10.426  0.7000 -0.4471  0.3442
3BGL     H515973   4.528  18.725  10.363 -0.4525  1.0824 -0.1756
3BGL     O515974   4.342  18.651  10.331  0.1934  0.1445  0.2786
3BGL     C115975   4.322  18.744  10.238  0.0047 -0.4785  0.1790
3BGL     H115976   4.416  18.778  10.194 -0.9920  1.9578 -0.2411
3BGL     C215977   4.251  18.864  10.310 -0.6103  0.0598 -0.3355
3BGL     H215978   4.153  18.842  10.352  0.6769 -0.5089  2.5981
```

Every six line I add one in $1 1BGL -> 2BGL. How to do that?

I try something like that, but I don't know what's next:

```
#!/bin/bash
index=1
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if (i = 6) index=index+1; print $1=($index)BGL  }' after_SOL.gro | tee after_SOL2.gro
```

To summarize I try do something like that

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

to

```
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Simple solution without using function.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  ++count
  value=count"BGL"
}
{
  $1=value
}
1
FNR%6==0{
  ++count
  value=count"BGL"
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program from here.
function add_counter() {     ##Creating function named add_counter here.
  ++count                    ##increment value of count with 1.
  value=count"BGL"           ##Creating variable value whose value is count and string BGL here.
}
FNR==1{                      ##Checking condition if FNR==1 then do following.
  add_counter()              ##Calling function add_counter here.
}
{
  $1=value                   ##Assigning variable value to current 1st field of current line.
}
1                            ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited lines here.
FNR%6==0{                    ##Checking condition if FNR%6==0 then do following.
  add_counter()              ##Calling function add_counter here.
}
'  Input_file                ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With function approach:

```
awk '
function add_counter() {
  ++count
  value=count"BGL"
}
FNR==1{
  add_counter()
}
{
  $1=value
}
1
FNR%6==0{
  add_counter()
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you. Where did you learn awk. I cant find very good course. 
I use $0 instead of 1 for example

Comment: Thank you. Where did you learn awk. I cant find very good course. 
I use $0 instead of 1 for example to print the whole line, I didnt know that I can use "1" instead of $0. 
`
$0
FNR%6==0{
  add_counter()
}
`
I dont know that, why you check that FNR==1? You check that there is a line and it stops at the end of file?

Comment: @Jakub, I learnt awk from man page of it, for explanation I believe I added a detailed level of explanation in my post please check it and lemme know then

Comment: @Jakub, I just went to SO page of awk tag and got this book https://archive.org/details/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7 you could read this book for learning awk

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` solution that uses just modulo arithmetic:

```
awk '{$1 = value ? value : $1} 1; NR%6 == 0{value = int(NR/6)+1 "BGL"}' file.csv |
column -t

1BGL  HO215593  3.915  12.459  9.510   0.7361   0.5777   -0.8536
1BGL  C315594   3.857  12.492  9.774   0.2903   -0.0441  -0.1309
1BGL  H315595   3.832  12.596  9.751   -1.5776  -0.7625  -1.5600
1BGL  O315596   3.751  12.409  9.734   -0.2728  0.1281   -1.1830
1BGL  HO315597  3.765  12.318  9.754   -0.2825  -0.0472  -1.9431
1BGL  O415858   6.570  4.320   11.610  0.3536   0.6453   -0.6513
2BGL  HO415859  6.659  4.351   11.619  0.0436   1.3871   -0.0553
2BGL  H6115861  6.645  4.607   11.335  2.0665   -1.6099  -1.7335
2BGL  H6215862  6.721  4.472   11.418  -0.2311  0.3617   1.3831
2BGL  O615863   6.688  4.666   11.503  0.0747   -0.9278  0.2467
2BGL  HO615864  6.676  4.744   11.451  0.9074   -1.0786  -0.1851
2BGL  C515972   4.449  18.685  10.426  0.7000   -0.4471  0.3442
3BGL  H515973   4.528  18.725  10.363  -0.4525  1.0824   -0.1756
3BGL  O515974   4.342  18.651  10.331  0.1934   0.1445   0.2786
3BGL  C115975   4.322  18.744  10.238  0.0047   -0.4785  0.1790
3BGL  H115976   4.416  18.778  10.194  -0.9920  1.9578   -0.2411
3BGL  C215977   4.251  18.864  10.310  -0.6103  0.0598   -0.3355
3BGL  H215978   4.153  18.842  10.352  0.6769   -0.5089  2.5981
```

`column -t` is being used to get tabular data, you may skip it if you don't need it.